# Pass username/password from Windows Forms application to an ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, security

Here is the situation:

- C# Windows Forms application
- ASP.NET web application
- Both authenticate with a custom user table in the same database (usename/password) and create a User object that is used throughout both applications

A user is logged into the Windows Forms application and we want to launch a URL to open a page in the ASP.NET web application in the default browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc.).  We want to pass the current username/password from the Windows Forms application to the ASP.NET web application in order to keep the user from having to log into the web application separately.

Based on our research, here are some options we have found (and the drawbacks):

- Pass username/password in URL as QueryStrings and create the User object in the web application

  - Not secure (password visible in URL)
- Create a temporary HTML page on the client machine that includes a JavaScript OnLoad function that POSTs username/password to the target URL and create the User object in the web application

  - (Could not find a way to POST data directly to a URL and display URL in default browser using C#)
  - Not secure (password visible in temporary page)
- Create a "Handoff" table to store username/password with a key that gets passed to the page via QueryString and deleted from the table when the page loads and create the User object in the web application

  - Small potential for key to be intercepted (hackers)
- Have a separate MongoDB that stores the User object and retrieve it in the web application

  - Separate software (MongoDB) running - additional point of failure

All of this is so that the user doesn't have to type their username/password twice to log into both applications.

Which one of the above options above would work best (most secure, least overhead/maintenance)?

**OR**

Is there a way to create a Forms Authentication ticket (cookie?) in the C# application that could be used by the default browser?

**OR**

Is there a better, secure method for handling this?

(edit)

**OR**

Is there a good argument for requiring the user to enter the username/password again to access the web application if they're already authenticated from the Windows Forms application?  If so, can you provide links to references?  Best practices, web security standards, etc.

Comment: I didn't think about it, but the Login.aspx page uses the ASP.NET Login control.  It also includes a "ReturnUrl" QueryString value for redirecting to a target page.  Doesn't that control just use POST anyway?  Could we just POST somehow to the Login.aspx page with a ReturnUrl of the target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could salt+MD5 the password and send it simply with the URL.

However, you should point to a script on the server first, which authenticates the user <strike>and creates the appropriate cookies</strike>, and redirects to the desired page, now without the credentials in the URL.

*edited: or basically do whatever you want to preserve the users' session*

Unfortunately, as long as passwords are involved, you can't be 100% secure. Still, hashing a [salted (salting is when you concatenate the password with some other string before hashing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) password might be your best bet if somebody can get a visual on the passwords.

1. You generate the password hash, with salt.
2. You send it to be processed (I usually just put it into the URL of a separate script, but it's a matter of preference.)
3. You generate a hash with the same salt on the server and check it against the submitted one.
4. Authenticate the user and redirect to the original location.

Comment: Is that basically like our comment above, POSTing to the Login.aspx page and redirecting to the target URL?  How secure is salt+MD5?  Can you point us to an example of how to do that?

Comment: I prefer using a separate script in case you ever need different functionality. Salting is pretty secure, even if you know what the salt string is, it adds some randomness to the hash, making rainbow tables less useful. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx)'s SHA1 class to create hashes (you can go with MD5, too, again, matter of preference)

Comment: So basically, something like: string hash = GenerateMD5Hash("MySalt" + username + "|" + password); then open a url like: MyPage.aspx?hash=(generated hash string).  In MyPage.aspx, grab the value from the QueryString, de-salted-hash it to get username|password and authenticate and redirect accordingly?  Easy enough, but is it truly more secure than just passing username/password in querystring (if someone gets a hold of the salt)?

Comment: I should have read 3. more carefully.  De-salted-hash doesn't make sense since it's inherently un-de-hashable.  Instead of passing the password around, you're validating it against a similar hash. So we would need to pass the username and the salted hash in the QueryString (username=bob&hash=<hash>)?  Wouldn't that be the same as using the password if you're checking the salted hash of the password against another salted hash of the same password?

Comment: You _have_ to send the user name unhashed. It can be part of the hash too, but the server has to know somehow who tries to log in. So it'd be: _desktoplogin.aspx?user=johndoe&hash=abc123_ Where hash is something like _"SecretSaltString" + userPassword_ hashed with MD5/SHA1.

Comment: After that, the server checks if _hash function("SecretSaltString" + password of your user)_ equals _hash function("SecretSaltString" + given password)_ You need the unencrypted user ID to determine whose password you want to compare the input to.

Comment: Wouldn't anyone with the QueryString (user=johndoe&hash=abc123) be able to access the system as that user, even though the password is hashed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12129/discussion-between-ics-and-mate-gelei)

Comment: After all of this, we found it still wasn't secure enough for our needs.  What we ended up doing was using Sys.Services.AuthenticationService and a C# WebBrowser control (ObjectForScripting=true).  The control calls a JavaScript function to authenticate the user via the MembershipProvider and redirect appropriately.  This was an excellent primer on hashing, though, which will prove useful for us later.  Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

In additional to what Máté Gelei has contributed, you could also include a timestamp in the Url and check to make sure the timestamp falls within a few seconds of current time.  This is a little added protection and ensures the login attempt becomes invalid very quickly.  Of course, you would want to somehow hide the purpose of this to make it a bit more secure.

This does not make it 100% secure, but it does add one more level of protection.

Comment: If you can deface the timestamp enough, but not beyond repair, it could work. It only slightly enhances security, but with a minimal effort, so feel free to go for it. Note that hashing wouldn't work, because it'd be impossible to reverse.